# cntk avg classification error > 1

Tags: python, cntk

[using CNTK '2.0.beta12.0' from python]
I am trying to evaluate my 19 class classification model using "classification_error(z, label)" and calling "trainer.previous_minibatch_evaluation_average()" after training and testing  minibatches.  The avg returned on the training set is ".725" (reasonable) but the avg returned on the test set is "3.875" (confusing).

I thought classification error was calculated as the average 0 or 1 value for each sample's prediction/label comparison, so I expected the avg returned to always be between 0 and 1.

Does anyone know if this error is calculated differently, or a common mistake that might lead to this sort of problem?

Thanks, Roland.

Comment: Additional Info: I just discovered if I make my test minibatch size the same as my training size, the avg returned looks right (and is always between 0 and 1).  My training mb size=200 and my test mb size=1000; if I multiply my correct test avg by 5, I get the reported test avg when using the mb size=1000.

Comment: So, is this a CNTK bug, or is the design that I cannot change the minibatch size?  Thanks...

Comment: You should just click the "edit" link underneath your post to add additional information.  Please add the code you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CNTK limitation/bug.  The workaround I used is to scale the returned average error by the ratio of minibatch to test sizes:

```
avgTestError = float(trainer.previous_minibatch_evaluation_average)  
# correct for CNTK bug  
avgTestError *= minibatch_size / len(xTest)
```